# Rank Equation for non-square Matrix

Tags: matrix-rank

If I have a $n\times d$ matrix $A$, can we say $rank(A) + null(A) = rank(A^T) + null(A^T)$? 
Also, is $rank (A) + null(A) = max(n,d)$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! I see someone already edited this post of yours, but please learn to format your posts [according to the rules of the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The ranks of a matrix and its transpose are equal.

Answer (score 0):

$1$.Offcourse not. Take $A$ with $n\ne d$, then $null(A)\ne null(A^T)$, etc.

$2$. $rank(A)+null(A)=$no. of columns$=d$

Answer (score 0):

The rank-nullity theorem implies $\text{rank}(A) + \text{null}(A) = d$ and $\text{rank}(A^\top) + \text{null}(A^\top) = n$.

So your first question is equivalent to $$d=n?$$ and your second question is equivalent to $$d = \max(n,d)?$$